# Bidirectional JSON-RPC over TCP socket Java implementation

Tags: java, sockets, bidirectional, json-rpc

Does anyone know if some Java implementation of the JSON-RPC protocol exists with bidirectional support (there is no Client/Server, both entities can send and receive the same messages).

I know it exists in Python: [bjsonrpc](http://deavid.github.com/bjsonrpc/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it didn't exist, so I created one, based on JsonRpcBase: [JJsonRpc](https://github.com/nbarraille/JJsonRpc)

It doesn't handle sockets connections very well right now, but it's working decently for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this the other day, might be worth looking at (I know this is out of date, but its all for the informations).

http://java-json-rpc.sourceforge.net/